# store the specific property from the bonded object of the select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Hi I've the following code in the controller:

```
$scope.rcOperators = [
  { sign: '=', operator: 'eq' },
  { sign: '!=', operator: 'ne' },
  { sign: '>', operator: 'gt' },
  { sign: '<', operator: 'lt' }
 ];
 $scope.rcOperator = '=';
```

I need to bind the array to `select` but I need to show in the `select` the sign[s], and to "store" in rcOperator the operator[s], I did the following to show the sign[s]:

```
<select ng-model="rcOperator"
  ng-options="s.sign for s in rcOperators">
</select>
```

the second step how can I store the operator in the `rcOperator`?

Answer (score 0):

In the controller you can get the value of `rcOperator` just you can `$scope.rcOperator.operator` then you can get the data of selected operator in model.